# SQL outcomes while running SQL scripts through Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby

I am using [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_database_access.htm) tutorial to run SQL commands via ruby. The point is to write a small script and automate so it runs every day using cron. Anyway, I want to know if anyone knows how to get the ruby script to output the outcome of running those SQL commands?

For example, if the update is successful, it should say 1 (or any number) row affected. Or some thine like that. I am not using Rails platform for this. Just ruby dbi gem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about DBI, never used it, but, for example, [`Sequel`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) docs says that [`update`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-method-i-update) returns number of updated rows, however, that's adapter-specific, i.e. not all database servers return the number of updated rows.